# Packaging Python Computer Vision application into executable

Tags: python, python-packaging

I have a python program in which I am using modules like opencv and tensorflow and yolo sometimes. I have tried different methods like pyinstaller, py2exe and auto-py-to-exe but it didnt work for me I guess. Is there a way, that I can create an .exe having all the libraries and media files like video and images (that were used in the program)?

Comment: Is it possible that you have not been using Pyinstaller and the rest probably? I always have very good experience with Pyisntaller.

Answer (score 0):

Please post the errors you are getting in detail. I used PyInstaller a lot with good experience. Solutions to some common issues you could find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pyinstaller).